# How to generate data using default_rng choice so that the generated data is imbalanced?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to generate some fake experimental data to play around with. What I'm struggling with is to determine the balance of the data for some variables/features.

Most importantly, the 'response' variable would ideally be imbalanced so that I can paly around with the treatment effect in the analysis later. But also in general so that the data is not super uniform.

All I can think of is to maybe not generate the data from a normal distribution, but this doesn't give me proper control.

This is my code so far:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)



# Sample size
size = 10000

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'treatment': rng.integers(0,2, size=size),
    'response': rng.integers (0,2, size=size)
    
})
```

When I run this I get:

```
df.groupby('treatment')['response'].mean()
```

0: 0.501696

1: 0.513530

But would like to have control over what the difference between treatment 0 and treatment 1. And generally just more control over all the variables.

Edit for solution:
Thanks to @noob and @lezaf for pointing me in the right direction.

The issue is that while you can get `rng.choice` to bias the probability of the choice, it does so equally for everyone and doesn't do it across treatment and control groups.

My workaround is to create two response variables with each bias and to then create a new response variable that takes its value from the previous two response variables depending on their treatment assignment.

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)


# Sample size
size = 10000



df = pd.DataFrame({
    'treatment': rng.integers(0,2, size=size),
    'response1': rng.choice ([0,1], size=size, p=[0.1, 0.9]),
    'response2': rng.choice ([0,1], size=size, p=[0.9, 0.1])
    
})


df['response'] = np.where(df['treatment']==1, df['response1'], df['response2'])
```

The alternative solution would be to create two separate DFs for treatment and control with their own probabilities, then concat.

Comment: This question is too open. It's better suited for cross validated stack exchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ but even there you need to give more details.

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree. This isn't a question of statistics or methods, this is a question specifically about the package and how to utilise it. Nonetheless, I've added a bit more explanation in case that helps to clarify things more.

Comment: Which package? You don't state that. There are a lot of hidden assumptions in your question, it's very specific. Can you make it simpler? Too many variables, not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#you can set the probabilities as you like
probs = [0.9, 0.1]

df['response'] = rng.choice([0, 1], size=size, p=probs)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't change the output.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `response` is a binary attribute since you create it with values from `low=0 (inclusive)` to `high=2 (exclusive)`. Therefore, it is not possible to get a `mean > 1` as you mention in both cases. So, how did you get these values?

Anyway, you can control the **bias** of the data generated using `numpy.random.Generator.choice` changing parameter `p`. From [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html):

> **p: *1-D array_like, optional*** 
> The probabilities associated with each entry in a. If not given, the sample assumes a uniform distribution over all entries in a.

Simplified example:

```
In [1]: rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'treatment': rng.choice([0,1], size=10000, p=[0.5, 0.5]),
                           'response': rng.choice([0,1], size=10000, p=[0.3, 0.7])})

In [3]: df.groupby('treatment')['response'].mean()
Out[3]:
treatment
0    0.702729
1    0.705992
```

Which makes sense since `response` takes value 1 with a `bias=0.7`. Also, probabilities for `treatment` attribute are irrelevant to the **mean** of *response*, thus I made it uniform in the example.

Comment: Hi Lezaf, thanks for your response. Regarding your initial question. I think I'd accidentally run it with `rng.choice` rather than `rng.integers` as I had written in my example code above. The latter is correct and produces output where `mean < 1`. Thanks for flagging that.

Comment: Regarding the use of `P`, @noob had also recommended this. And while this is partially the solution, the issue I've realised is that `P` doesn't apply the probabilities to the different treatment groups. I've now instead create a workaround for this in my original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. I'm not sure what you mean by the fact that 'P doesn't apply the probabilities to the different treatment groups'. I suppose that it works fine but it doesn't fit to what you try to do. In any case, bear in mind that you can use any distribution from scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#probability-distributions to create your sample with something more than a simple *bias*.

Comment: Ah yeah, I meant it works fine, but what I needed was different probabilities for the treatment and control group. Thanks!